# Seeking in video players inside UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

I’m having some scroll / touch woes.

I have a `UICollectionView` with a few cells arranged horizontally, each of which contains one of YouTube’s lovely `YTPlayerView` instances. Basically, it’s a little web view that loads a YouTube video.

Problem is, if I try to seek in those videos, i.e. by grabbing the handle and panning horizontally, the collection view gets all up in its face and I end up scrolling the collection view instead.

I have no access to the pan recognizers inside the YouTube player, so how can I stop the touch being passed through to the collection view in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution, though I cannot explain it, so if anyone can I’d still gladly award the correct answer points.

I was creating the cell from a NIB, and using `registerNib` on the collection view. I switched that to using `registerClass` and set up the player inside `initWithFrame` instead, so removed the NIB, and it all worked perfectly.

Comment: I am also using `YTPlayerView` inside `UICollectionView` (Horizontal scroll) with one custom cell visible at a time on the screen. I have added a `UIView` inside custom cell and changed the class name to `YTPlayerView` in Identity inspector. For `YTPlayerView` I have enabled AutoPlay. When I scroll to next or previous item I want to stop the player. I tried stopping the player in 'didEndDisplayingCell' by getting custom cell object. But YTPlayerView instance with custom cell object returns `(null)`. So I am not able to stop video play. How can I stop video play when scroll to next / prev item?